# Why is my cars acceleration not working properly?

Tags: buick

I drive a 2005 Buick Rendezvous. It has been driving well until just recently. I drove it around for several hours the other day and it started to have slow and rough acceleration. I was only going 60-65.

I just had an oil change a week ago. They didn't replace the air filter like I normally have changed. They said it was still good.

Comment: 60-65 km/h or mph?

Comment: I was on the highway so no more than 70 mph

Comment: Could it possibly be my timing belt?

Comment: Plugs? Coils? It's probably unrelated to the oil change.

Comment: When was the last time this vehicle had a full service tune-up?

Comment: You're going to need to include more information for anyone to be able to help you. Right now, there isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: which engine do you have?

Comment: Clogged fuel filter?  Bad gas?